# Installing an event filter on a QScrollArea viewport

Tags: c++, qt, oop, architecture, qt5

I have a custom `QWidget` in a `QScrollArea` that belongs to a top-level `QWidget`. The layout is created using Qt Designer. I'd like to intercept mouse move or hover events, neither of which appear in the custom widget, obviously due to it being placed into a `QScrollArea`. I know the solution is to install an event filter onto `QScrollArea::viewport()`. The question is about the architecture of the solution and the connections between the objects regarding the problem described below.

When a mouse event occurs and is intercepted by the event filter installed on the viewport of the `QScrollArea`, I need to call `QScrollArea::mapFromGlobal()` in order to obtain the coordinates of the event relative to the custom widget. However, the custom widget knows nothing about the scroll area or the event filter. Hence, is the following architecture correct:

1. The top level widget instantiates the custom widget and the scroll area (let's forget that it's done via Qt Designer at the moment, we need the aggregation-composition-etc lifetime management aspect), adds the widget to the layout of the scroll area, then instantiates the event filter and sets it onto the custom widget.
2. The event filter emits a signal with the global mouse event position whenever a mouse event is intercepted in the custom widget.
3. The top level widget reacts to the signal and invokes `QScrollArea::mapFromGlobal()`.
4. The top level widget then calls the appropriate method, i.e. `handleMouseHOver()`, in the custom widget.

This way, the top level widget is the mediator between the entities. Another approach is as follows:

1. Identical to 1 above.
2. The event filter is programmed to know about the scroll area.
3. The event filter calls `QScrollArea::mapFromGlobal()` and emits a signal with the global mouse event position whenever it intercepts a mouse event in the custom widget.
4. The custom widget subscribes to that signal and reacts accordingly.

This way, the top level widget only instantiates the entities, and lets them handle the business on their own.

Edit: Now I've learnt about one more approach, where the top-level widget reimplements `QObject::eventFilter()` and then installs itself onto the target widget as the event filter: `someWidget->installEventFilter(this);`. How correct is this from the architecture standpoint? This way, the top-level widget has two responsibilities at the very least. Isn't it better to factor out the event filter code into a separate class?

I've noticed that it's hard to talk about architecture with Qt since signals and slots defy the notion of interface, thus the rule "program against an interface" is almost invalidated. Anything can connect to to where it wants. Still, the above problem has at least tho possible entity layouts, and probably even more.

Is my approach correct, and is it in any way similar to how it should be done in Qt5 with QWidgets and C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Mouse Tracking to the Rescue

The good news are: no explicit event management is necessary. Once you enable mouse tracking on the child widget, Qt will pass relevant events to it, even when there's an intervening `QScrollArea`. To wit:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/scrollarea-filter-40605540
#include <QtWidgets>

class Tracker : public QFrame {
   QPoint pos;
   void invalidatePos() { pos.setX(-1); }
   bool isPosInvalid() const { return pos.x() < 0; }
   void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override {
      pos = event->pos();
      update();
   }
   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override {
      QFrame::paintEvent(event);
      if (isPosInvalid()) return;
      QPainter p{this};
      p.setPen(Qt::red);
      p.setBrush(Qt::red);
      p.drawEllipse(pos, 4, 4);
   }
   void leaveEvent(QEvent *event) {
      invalidatePos();
      update();
      QFrame::leaveEvent(event);
   }
public:
   Tracker(QWidget * parent = nullptr) : QFrame{parent} {
      setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel);
      setLineWidth(2);
      setMouseTracking(true);
   }
};

class TopWidget : public QWidget {
   QVBoxLayout m_layout{this};
   QScrollArea m_area;
   QWidget m_child;
   Tracker m_tracker{&m_child};
public:
   TopWidget(QWidget * parent = nullptr) : QWidget{parent} {
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_area);
      m_area.setWidget(&m_child);
      m_child.setMinimumSize(1024, 1024);
      m_tracker.setGeometry(150, 150, 300, 300);
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   TopWidget ui;
   ui.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

#### Aside About Signals And Slots

First of all, signals and slots **certainly** provide interfaces: they are the essence of an interface, for they provide one of **the** means to decrease coupling in the code. The "anything can connect to where it wants" observation is only partially correct: it's true only *as long as the signals or slots are the part of an interface*.

For example, suppose that you have a user interface widget displays coordinates. While it's true that the interfaces of the individual sub-controls can be connected to at will, these controls are encapsulated and you certainly can't directly connect to them as a user of `CoordinateDialog` - not unless you use introspection to bypass encapsulation:

```
class CoordinateDialog : public QDialog {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QVector3D value READ value WRITE setValue NOTIFY coordinatesChanged)
   QVector3D m_value;
   QFormLayout m_layout{this};
   QDoubleSpinBox m_x, m_y, m_z;
   QDialogButtonBox m_buttons;
public:
   CoordinateDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : CoordinateDialog(QVector3D(), parent) {}
   CoordinateDialog(const QVector3D &value, QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
      QDialog{parent}, m_value(value)
   {
      m_layout.addRow("X", &m_x);
      m_layout.addRow("Y", &m_y);
      m_layout.addRow("Z", &m_z);
      m_layout.addRow(&m_buttons);
      m_buttons.addButton(QDialogButtonBox::Ok);
      m_buttons.addButton(QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
      connect(&m_buttons, &QDialogButtonBox::accepted, this, &QDialog::accept);
      connect(&m_buttons, &QDialogButtonBox::rejected, this, &QDialog::reject);
      connect(&m_x, static_cast<void (QDoubleSpinBox::*)(double)>(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
              [=](double x){ auto v = m_value; v.setX(x); setValue(v); });
      connect(&m_y, static_cast<void (QDoubleSpinBox::*)(double)>(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
              [=](double y){ auto v = m_value; v.setY(y); setValue(v); });
      connect(&m_z, static_cast<void (QDoubleSpinBox::*)(double)>(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
              [=](double z){ auto v = m_value; v.setZ(z); setValue(v); });
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void coordinatesChanged(const QVector3D &);
   Q_SIGNAL void coordinatesAccepted(const QVector3D &);
   void accept() override {
      emit coordinatesAccepted(m_value);
      QDialog::accept();
   }
   QVector3D value() const { return m_value; }
   Q_SLOT void setValue(const QVector3D &value) {
      if (m_value == value) return;
      m_value = value;
      m_x.setValue(m_value.x());
      m_y.setValue(m_value.y());
      m_z.setValue(m_value.z());
      emit coordinatesChanged(m_value);
   }
};
```

As a user of this class, your interface is that of a `QDialog` and of the methods (including signals and slots) added by the `CoordinateDialog`. The `&QPushButton::clicked` signal is not in the interface, even though there are pushbuttons on the dialog and they certainly emit such a signal.

Comment: Sorry, been quite busy for a while, I'm not sure tracking worked like that for me, at the moment I've implemented one of the approaches described in the question, will test if just tracking is going to work. One thing I've noticed that even for my approach it's necessary to turn  tracking on throughout the whole stack: the scroll area, the viewport, and the custom widget contained in the viewport.

Comment: The above is a complete example. You can download it, compile it and it should work. It's tested. Does it not work for you? Are your requirements somehow different? If so, please edit your question to indicate what special requirements you have.